# Internal error for Jetty plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jetty

When using the Eclipse Jetty plugin (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-jetty?mpc=true&mpc_state=), I started to get the following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching myProject".
Unknown scope: test,provided
```

This started to occur for two separate projects, both on Windows and MacOs X systems. Note that a regular Jetty deployment, as well as the Jetty runner Maven plugin, work like a charm, the problem seems to be with the Eclipse plugin only. The problem persists after upgrading the plugin to the newest version. Changing Jetty versions doesn't help as well.

edit: Thanks for the tips so far. The question is what might be the source of this problem and how to get rid of it. The relevant log message is as follows:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-04-27 09:01:40.914 
>   !MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching myProject". 
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown scope: test,provided
>       at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.util.MavenScope.to(MavenScope.java:109)
>       at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.util.MavenDependencyInfo.create(MavenDependencyInfo.java:98)
>       at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.util.MavenDependencyInfoMap.resolve(MavenDependencyInfoMap.java:141)
>       at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.util.Dependency.create(Dependency.java:39)
>       at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.launch.util.JettyLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getOriginalClasspathEntries(JettyLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:340)
>       at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.launch.util.JettyLaunchConfigurationDelegate.createJettyConfigurationFile(JettyLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:791)
>       at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.launch.util.JettyLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getVMArguments(JettyLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:217)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaLaunchDelegate.launch(JavaLaunchDelegate.java:64)
>       at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.launch.util.JettyLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(JettyLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:192)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Eclipse with a console and debug info to see if more error details are available: add `-console`, `-consoleLog` and `-debug` to your `eclipse.ini` to achieve this.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Perhaps. The original post should probably be worded as a specific question as well. :) I'll edit based on how the conversation goes.

Comment: All that said, @greg-449, if you know where to find them, could you provide a link to the comment vs. answer and question guidelines? I was unable to readily find them when looking recently. Thanks. :)

Comment: It is pretty straightforward, an answer must be a definitive answer to the question - not a suggestion about things to try. See [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Yes, I agree that this question can't be answered in its current form.

Comment: :) Yes, agreed. I'll try to tidy up later today if possible. Thanks for the etiquette tip.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the Run Jetty Run plugin instead of the Maven Jetty plugin